# How to clean the input search without hiding the keyboard ? (mobile)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic/AngularJS and that's my question, every time I clean up the input, the keyboard disappears and I don't want that

```
<ion-header-bar ng-show="searchBoxEnabled">
  <div>
    <input type="search"
           ng-model="query">
    <div ng-show="query"
         ng-click="query=''"> <!--must ONLY clean the input, but is
                                  also disappearing the keyboard-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--must clean the input and disappear the keyboard,
      this one is working properly-->
  <div ng-click="hideSearchBox(); query=''">
    |Cancel
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

and in the javascript side I have this couple functions in order to show and hide the input

```
$scope.showSearchBox = function() {
  $scope.searchBoxEnabled = true;
};

$scope.hideSearchBox = function() {
  $scope.searchBoxEnabled = false;
};
```

Comment: I don't think it is clear the input that hides the keyboard, its is clicking the button. Clicking the button triggers a blur event on the input. In your hideSearchBox() function, refocus on an input element. This may cause the  keyboard to hide and then reappear though.

Comment: so, what can I do ? @ConnorFinnMcKelvey

Comment: In the `ng-click` you could re-focus the input so the keyboard should appear again. I guess you would want to create a directive for this. Or just let the user click the input again themselves of course.

Comment: @Rhumborl how can I do that ? is there an standard method or I need to create a function ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer, did the answer below address your question?

Comment: @NewDev I could not adapt it to my code, I was trying to do it with an input search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that it is probably the `blur` event on the input that causes the keyboard to go away.

You could solve this with a directive on the button that refocuses on the input following a click (although I have no way to verify whether this would cause a flicker with a keyboard).

Here's an illustrative example where you pass the ID of the element that you want to refocus to:

```
app.directive("refocus", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on("click", function() {
        var id = attrs.refocus;
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        el.focus();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

and the usage is:

```
<input id="foo" ng-model="newItem">
<button ng-click="doSomething(newItem)" refocus="foo">add</button>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dmSMJS72gT2PDwv8wpjV?p=preview)

Comment: And if you add ionic bundle .js your code will stop working
code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js